# MongoDB shard ranges overlap

Tags: mongodb, sharding

I have following configuration of Mongo DB cluster:

- App server with installed **mongos**
- 3 different servers with installed **mongoc** (mongoc0, mongoc1, mongoc2)
- 2 Replica sets with groups of 3 servers each running **mongod** (rs: mongodb0-0, mongodb0-1, mongodb0-2; rs1: mongodb1-0, mongodb1-1, mongodb1-2)

After unexpected reboot of application server I had found out that mongos started to show error while I try to run **show collections**.

```
mongos> show collections;
  Mon Feb  3 22:50:21.680 error: {
    "$err" : "error loading initial database config information :: caused by :: Couldn't load a valid config for database.stats_archive_monthly after 3 attempts. Please try again.",
    "code" : 13282
  } at src/mongo/shell/query.js:128
```

However, all **mongo** servers and **mongo config** servers were healthy and have no issues in logs.

First of all I tried to reboot each of the server in cluster with no success. Error still occurs.

Then after a little check of mongo source I found out that this error could be caused by overlapping ranges of shard keys.

Looking into shard information for broken collection, I noticed this:

```
    database.stats_archive_monthly
        shard key: { "a" : "hashed" }
        chunks:
            rs1 6
            rs0 6
        { "a" : { "$minKey" : 1 } } -->> { "a" : NumberLong("-7686143364045646500") } on : rs1 Timestamp(2, 0)
        { "a" : NumberLong("-7686143364045646500") } -->> { "a" : NumberLong("-6148914691236517200") } on : rs1 Timestamp(3, 0)
        { "a" : NumberLong("-6148914691236517200") } -->> { "a" : NumberLong("-4611686018427387900") } on : rs1 Timestamp(4, 0)
        { "a" : NumberLong("-4611686018427387900") } -->> { "a" : NumberLong("-3074457345618258600") } on : rs1 Timestamp(5, 0)
        { "a" : NumberLong("-3074457345618258600") } -->> { "a" : NumberLong("-1537228672809129300") } on : rs1 Timestamp(6, 0)
        { "a" : NumberLong("-1537228672809129300") } -->> { "a" : NumberLong(0) } on : rs1 Timestamp(7, 0)
        { "a" : NumberLong(0) } -->> { "a" : NumberLong("7686143364045646500") } on : rs0 Timestamp(7, 1)
        { "a" : NumberLong("1537228672809129300") } -->> { "a" : NumberLong("3074457345618258600") } on : rs0 Timestamp(1, 9)
        { "a" : NumberLong("3074457345618258600") } -->> { "a" : NumberLong("4611686018427387900") } on : rs0 Timestamp(1, 10)
        { "a" : NumberLong("4611686018427387900") } -->> { "a" : NumberLong("6148914691236517200") } on : rs0 Timestamp(1, 11)
        { "a" : NumberLong("6148914691236517200") } -->> { "a" : NumberLong("7686143364045646500") } on : rs0 Timestamp(1, 12)
        { "a" : NumberLong("7686143364045646500") } -->> { "a" : { "$maxKey" : 1 } } on : rs0 Timestamp(1, 13)
```

There is range

```
{ "a" : NumberLong(0) } -->> { "a" : NumberLong("**7686143364045646500**") } on : rs0 Timestamp(7, 1)
```

that is overlapping all shard keys from first replica set.

For some additional statistics:
First replica set contains 73 records, second replica set contain 0 records. (It is staging environment, God bless for it...)

```
rs0:PRIMARY> db.stats_archive_monthly.count();
73

rs1:PRIMARY> db.stats_archive_monthly.count();
0
```

Only one query that work with this collection is:
    $mongo_db['stats_archive_monthly'].update( {a: account_id, l_id: location_id, t: time.truncate(interval())}, {'$set' => {u: data.to_i}}, upsert: true)

Do you have any ideas of why it could happen? How ranges could overlap during work? Cluster works well for half a year without any maintenance.

My suggestion is to drop all collections and restore all from backup, but I still have time to play with corrupted DB and give you any info for being able to find what is going on here.

Comment: I think your confused by your output, the rs1 chunks are negative that number while the rs0 chunks are positive that number

Comment: I am not confused of negative and positive values for ranges. I also see that first range is from $minkey till -7686143364045646500 and last range is from 7686143364045646500 till $maxkey

Comment: What specific version of MongoDB and host O/S are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see it overlapping according to your status output, it says it goes from the last of the previous replica set to the maxkey as you can see with others:

```
{ "a" : { "$minKey" : 1 } } -->> { "a" : NumberLong("-7686143364045646500") } on : rs1 Timestamp(2, 0)
```

So this chunk on `rs1` ends at `-7686143364045646500` and:

```
{ "a" : NumberLong("-7686143364045646500") } -->> { "a" : NumberLong("-6148914691236517200") } on : rs1 Timestamp(3, 0)
```

This chunk starts after `-7686143364045646500`.

Your chunk on rs0 actually starts at NEGATIVE `7686143364045646500` and the chunk on rs1 starts at POSITIVE `7686143364045646500`.

And the query returning `0` rows looks correct too. If there was overlapping or duplicate chunks you wouldn't return `0` rows.

At the end of the day the collection will still be there if you told MongoDB to shard it, it just will be empty.

#### Edit

As for why your config servers are acting weird, hmmm.

#### Edit

Didn't see the middle chunk which does actually do it, edited question to make it clear.

Comment: Yeap, start is as you get it from -7... till -6...
But if you look further - ~
It goes from -1.. till 0
then from 0 till 7...
and then again from 1... till 3... and so on

I think that this one { "a" : NumberLong(0) } -->> { "a" : NumberLong("7686143364045646500") } on : rs0 Timestamp(7, 1)

should be { "a" : NumberLong(0) } -->> { "a" : NumberLong("1537228672809129300") } on : rs0 Timestamp(7, 1)

Or I have 4 last ranges included in one.

So for example one key 1537228672809129301 is included in two ranges

Comment: I have many other collections in the same db and all other collections have normal ranges in compare with this collection

Comment: @nexo Ok I didn't see the formatting of your question properly I see what you mean now, I think I may know the answer

Comment: @nexo Have you been deleting from the this? Did rs0 have data originally?

Comment: It has not. Since it is staging all data for this collection goes only on rs1, cause collection is hashed by attribute "a" and all records has {"a": 1}. I never delete any records from this table by myself, only by expiration index. Here how collection is created - db.adminCommand( { shardCollection: "stats_archive_monthly", key: {a: "hashed"}, numInitialChunks: 12 } )
db.stats_archive_monthly.ensureIndex( { "a": 1, "l_id":1, "t": 1 } )
db.stats_archive_monthly.ensureIndex( {t: 1}, { expireAfterSeconds: 2678400 + 604800} )

Comment: @nexo I wonder if something interesting could be going on with the TTL index. I believe that no data is overlapping (as I did before) what I believe is that status is misreporting chunks as still existing when they shouldn't. All I know is that the chunks below `0 - xxx` on rs0 should not be there, if they were it would mean that rs0 should have a lot of data.

Comment: Yeap, that is clear, but there is no too much data (72 records with whole size of 8Kb - It is less then one chunk region could handle), and as I see data is all in good place, all shards have it's own data and nothing special. I think that all db server's are good, but something was broken on config servers, and I could not find any reason for the problem neither normal way of fix for this problem, Only complete recreation of all DB from backup - but if this will happen in production it will create too many problems.

Comment: @nexo indeed, I have personally never had this, try posting on the google group I am sure it will get help from the right 10gen guy

Comment: @nexo though I mean if the shards cant get the config then it wouldn't have even taken ops, so it is weird that it took the config, said the config was down and then made a constantly out of date config...weird as hell

Comment: @nexo just found this: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/48232/mongodb-config-servers-not-in-sync

Comment: I've already seen this message. 1) "ERROR: config servers not in sync!" - All 3 config servers are in sync, data is the same, timestamps, hashes and all other stuff is the same, data in "config" db is the same. 2) dbhash shows that all hashes are the same, I tried to shutdown different 2 or 1 config server and recreate mongos server on different machine - no hope. 3) As I said before - all collections seem to be OK and has only data that they should have.

Comment: Yeap, I can't start cluster, running mongos get errors while getting collections list or trying to use "problem" collections direct